# How To Switch From Ubuntu 16.04 To Lubuntu

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, lenovo

Basically, not a techie at all, but trying to be. And I can follow directions well. Have a cheap old Lenovo laptop, and Ubuntu is too slow for me. I have 2GB of RAM and 1.6GHz.

Wanting to switch to Lubuntu, but have no idea how. I don't really know what it technically is called, but someone will ask...I don't insert a USB to boot, I just turn my computer on, and Ubuntu is first in the boot load.

I already installed lubuntu-desktop, but from what I understand, that just installs the desktop environment, but all of the Ubuntu processes that slow down older computers will still be running (and it certainly seems like it's still slow to me).

Are there any videos or step-by-step guides on how exactly to make the switch? I can re-install all of my apps, and re-login to all of my stuff, it's no problem. What might be the best way to do this? Factory reset, possibly? Not sure. Just trying to make the most out of my old laptop, so I can get rid of my MacBook finally.

Comment: If you are fine with setting everything up again, the cleanest solution would be a fresh installation of Lubuntu. Make a backup of your important data first because everything will be deleted in the process.

Comment: And I guess I was wondering exactly how to do the fresh installation. I mean, would I have to factory reset computer first, or what? As I said, I'm not a techie, I don't even remember how I installed Ubuntu, lol.

Comment: No, there is no "factory reset" involved because you are going to install a new operating system. There are tons of tutorials available online. You can have a look at the official [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) provided by canonical. The procedure usually involves creating a bootable medium containing the desired Ubuntu version/flavour and booting a live system from it. Installing Ubuntu is really easy, just make sure that you made a backup of your important data first.

Comment: Just a comment; after adding `lubuntu-desktop` did you select it at the login screen (assuming you didn't have auto-login; you can't do this change with auto-login) to use it.  Yes you end up with two sets of apps; eg. leafpad (used by LXDE) and gedit (Unity/gnome) are both editors, and with LXDE (Lubuntu) you lose its light advantage if you run gedit as it forces some GTK+3 libs (Unity/gnome) into memory to run , but you should have noticed a difference (though picking which app is which can be a hassle I bet if its new). Re-installing (clean) lubuntu removes those gtk+ (unity) apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 + Lubuntu-desktop is different than a freshly installed Lubuntu, and I agree the latter gives you a better experience than the former. (Lubuntu 18.04 is even better.)

Before installing Lubuntu to completely replace Ubuntu. I would make two, count them, two backups of everything in /home and verify they match what's on your PC.

Then, I would generate a list of everything installed on your PC with
`apt-cache pkgnames > apps.txt` and save apps.txt to a flashdrive. Once that completes, do a stock standard install of 16.04, run `apt-cache pkgnames > remove.txt` and manually edit apps.txt to take out of apps.txt which also appears in remove.txt. So, *apps.txt - remove.txt =* a list of everything added by you.

Now that you have the list of what to install, re-reboot that PC from a Lubuntu LiveUSB flashdrive, start installing, and when Ubiquity (the standard installer app) asks, what to do with partitioning, tell it to erase everything.

When Lubuntu's install completes and you have rebooted into the new system, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install < new-apps.txt
```

and Lubuntu will go and get all the programs which were not part of Lubuntu, and their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the console based "aptitude" or the graphical "Synaptic Package Manager", it should have a submenu called "Tasks".  One of them should be either "lubuntu-desktop" or "lxde-desktop".  Just mark the whole task for installation and wait a while.

I'm pretty sure it will run dpkg to change your boot splash to "Lubuntu" and set your login manager to LXDM.  In LXDM you'll still have the option to log in to the Unity Desktop instead of the LXDE desktop, unless you explicitly uninstall it.